# Angular2 component render to a div reference and not css selector

Tags: angular, selector

//inside iframe!

```
<script type="text/babel">
    var div = window.top.document.getElementById("parent_div");
    ReactDOM.render(
        <h1>Hi, this is ReactJS App here!!!</h1>,
        div
    );
</script>
```

This works in react, how to achieve this in Angular2/4?

I want to bootstrap the angular app from within an iframe but render it to parent frame's div.  Both the parent and iframe are loaded from same url.
Angular2/4 component selector has only css type of selector, is there a way to provide a div reference for the component to render?

Comment: provide a class to the div and then use viewChild that might help

Comment: short answer, 'no', long answer, 'no that is not possible'

Comment: @RahulSingh i think you didn't get my question fully, viewChild can only help for the current frame window.  I want to find a reference to div (at runtime) and bootstrap the component on that div..